# Woocommerce shipping option: just send email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My question is related to WooCommerce shipping methods.

I would like to give 2 shipping methods:

```
1. Shipping (Use a predefined shipping method) to send the gift certificate
2. Send by email
```

I can't define it as a virtual product because I need to use the shipping functionality. But at the same time I need to give the option to the user of just send an email before the checkout, so it will be a kind of virtual product without shipping, but dynamically.

I use the [WooCommerce Gift Certificates Pro](http://ignitewoo.com/woocommerce-extensions-plugins/woocommerce-gift-certificates-pro/) but it doesn't have the possibility to give the option to the user if he wants to ship it or send as email.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I renamed the `Local Pickup` option to `Send by Email`. Anyways the email is sent in all cases.

I needed to [remove the text (Free) from Local Pickup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304543/how-to-remove-the-text-free-from-local-pickup-in-shopping-cart-page-in-woocomm/23581605#23581605) in shopping cart.